# How to fix Couchbase ForestDB "File handle is busy" when deleting view?

Tags: java, android, couchbase-lite

When deleting from couchbase, screen freezes. 
I am deleting like so

```
resetViews1(db)
resetViews2(db)
resetViews3(db)
resetViews4(db)
resetViews5(db)
resetViews6(db)
resetViews7(db)
resetViews8(db)
resetViews9(db)
```

Where each resetViews method is calling

```
database.getView(view_id).delete()
```

I have pinpointed the freeze to come from resetViews7 method. Inspecting logcat it shows

```
`com.couchbase.cbforest.ForestException: file handle is busy'.
```

I have tried removing the 7th call and if removed the screen does not freeze up. Unsure why this is causing a screen freeze.

Comment: What version of Couchbase Lite is this?

Comment: I am using version 1.4.1

Comment: The screen probably freezes because you are calling an operation which could potentially block on the UI thread.

Comment: @borrrden  I was able to solve this by adding that particular operation into an Rx call.